# JQUERY: Increase Textarea Height when clicked bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this textarea where I want to increase it's height when clicked, I also added a DIV above it:

```
<div id = "postbox_container">
   <textarea id = "post_textarea" rows = "1" cols = "7" name = "text_post" placeholder = "Post..." required/></textarea>
</div>
```

It's CSS:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 97%;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 2.7vh;
padding: 1vh;
border: 0px solid #dedede;
resize: none;

transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

Finally my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#postbox_container').on('click', function(){

      $('#post_textarea').height('20vh');


    });

  });
```

This works but everytime I click the textarea, it adds a new height - so it becomes longer and longer the more you click on it. My point is that I want to make the textarea's height to a fixed `20vh` everytime the use clicks the DIV for the first time. Any ideas guys? Thanks.

Comment: Also, you should check your html it's not formatted correctly

Comment: Did you try with pixels and see if the same happens? `.height(20)` If not your html might be faulty.

Comment: It works correctly for me - I've created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xpmcxaqg/

Comment: me too it works correctly...
https://jsfiddle.net/69jn6zeu/

Comment: @RomanHocke I actually don't know ... it's probably my css messing with my jquery buy it works now. Thanks.

Comment: That's because @RomanHocke adjusted the html. On the snippet you provided, you're self-closing textarea and then closing it again

Comment: @VilleKoo Weird, even if I put the self-closing back, it works correctly (sets the height, does not increase it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a check that means this will only run the first time this is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clicked = false;
    $('#postbox_container').on('click', function(){

        if (!clicked) { 
          $('#post_textarea').height('20vh');
          clicked = true;
        }

    });

});
```

When the page loaded we know the box hasn't been clicked, then when we click it it we tell the browser this has already happened and set that to true - so when we click again the browser skips over the request to change the height.

To put the height back on focus out:

```
$( "#post_textarea" )
  .focusout(function() {
    $('#post_textarea').height('[set the height you want to return to]');
  })
```

Comment: His problem is jQuery incrementing height than setting it. This works only if it needs to be set only on first click.

Comment: Thanks! This actually works! I'm so dumbfounded by your answer haha. Out of the context but is there a way too that whenever the user is not focusing on the textarea, the textarea goes back to its original size and sets the `clicked` to false again? Thanks!

Comment: Surely that has the same effect though - if it's clicked once the height will remain fixed because if it's clicked again it won't change the height?

Comment: @WebDevelopWolf The focus out code doesn't work for me... when I click outside the text area, the textarea increases it's height. I think we're almost there

Comment: What did you set the height to?

Comment: @Dranreb you can use blur() function..!

Comment: Yeah that was going to be my next suggestion

Comment: set it to 1vh .. I guess that's probably it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/69jn6zeu/ - works in this fiddle - you can use blur or focusout - both should work

Comment: @WebDevelopWolf I figured out the problem! When you try change the css to `#postbox_container textarea` that's it. That's my original design. In here: https://jsfiddle.net/69jn6zeu/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can bind using one function.
But I have tested your code and it worked fine for me.

Here is the link

https://jsfiddle.net/Saiyam/x91ts87z/5/

```
$('#postbox_container').one('click', function(){
 $('#post_textarea').height('20vh');
});
```

This will bind only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a flag that changes to 'true' when a user clicks, next time check that flag and do nothing when the flag is 'true' like so.

```
var firstTime = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#postbox_container').on('click', function(){
        if(!firstTime){
            firstTime = true;
            $('#post_textarea').height('20vh');
        }
     });

});
```

Comment: His problem is jQuery incrementing height than setting it. This works only if it needs to be set only on first click.

Comment: @SachiDangalla no, his problem is his Textarea height increasing everytime user clicked in, he just wants height change for the first user's click.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments, if you wanted to get the textarea to revert it's size when its out of focus, you could do something like this.

I've deliberately used a slightly different approach to Web Develop Wolf (Good answer, +1) to show an alternative way of doing it.

CSS:

```
#postbox_container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 97%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2.7vh;
  padding: 1vh;
  border: 0px solid #dedede;
  resize: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#post_textarea.selected {
  height: 20vh;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#post_textarea').on('focus', function() {
    $('#post_textarea').addClass('selected');
  });

  $('#post_textarea').on('focusout', function() {
    $('#post_textarea').removeClass('selected');
  });

});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q25h394m/